# android project structure not showing in android studio flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I cloned this codelab's code from github: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7

I imported the starter folder only, since there are multiple folder for a complete code and non complete codes. The problem I has is that I can't change the project structure from "Project" to android to complete the last step of the codelab.
I'm not sure if I made a mistake while importing the project or if I should just change some configuration in android studio.

[image: android project structure to android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android project structure will not show there but you can open android module separately by going to

Tools > Flutter > Open For Editing In Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I just found another way but your way is better:  
 Open the android/build.gradle file (or any file under the android folder), and click Open for Editing in Android Studio to open an Android project.